# Avoid CSS Background Repeat

Tags: css

I've googled this like crazy and found that I need to use the background-repeat attribute, but for some reason it's not working for me.  I'm sure I just made a silly mistakes, but I can't figure it out for the life of me!

Thanks in advance!

```
body {
background-image: url('../images/main_bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can test with?

Comment: Is that your entire stylesheet? What do the browser F12 tools say what the final **computed** property value is?

Comment: What you are doing, looks correct. `background-repeat: no-repeat;` would work for you. if it is not happening then made a jsfiddle to show us.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work, where do you see the repeat occur (or do you have more code that could trigger that repeat)?
I don't see any problem:
http://jsbin.com/odenet/1/

*Note:*

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

- Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this if this works?
 `background:url(images/main_bg.png) no-repeat;`